# MYSQL results order is mixing

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT 
       GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(user_firstname,' ', user_lastname)) fullname,
       workour_day, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(distinct timetable_start) starttime, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(timetable_end) endtime 
FROM doctors_timetable 
INNER JOIN doctors ON user_id = doctor_id 
INNER JOIN workours ON timetable_day = workour_id GROUP BY workour_day 
ORDER BY timetable_id ASC
```

before Thursday everything works good and than it's mixing:

http://s24.postimg.org/w827dxclh/Capture.png

[image: Example]

MYSQL results order is mixing. How can I fix it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid
from Thursday starttime and endtime is mixed. for example starttime starts: 12:00:00, 16:00:00, 08:00:00. I want 08:00:00, 12:00:00, 16:00:00 and also endtime is mixed. Why results are good, before Thursday and bad after Thursday ?

Comment: To add to M Khalid Junaid's comment, we have no idea what 'timetable_id' is defined as, or what on earth 'mixing' means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As what i understand from your comment you need the starttime and endtitme values to be in ascending order if thats the case you can use `ORDER BY` in `GROUP_CONCAT` to tell in what order to concatenate values

```
SELECT 
       GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(user_firstname,' ', user_lastname)) fullname,
       workour_day, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(distinct timetable_start ORDER BY timetable_start ASC) starttime, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(timetable_end ORDER BY timetable_end) endtime 
FROM doctors_timetable 
INNER JOIN doctors ON user_id = doctor_id 
INNER JOIN workours ON timetable_day = workour_id
GROUP BY workour_day 
ORDER BY timetable_id ASC
```

Note you are using `GROUP_CONCAT` function which has a default limit of 1024 characters set by default,if your output exceeds this limit the result will be truncated to increase the limit you can see steps mentioned in the manual

Answer (score 0):

timetable_id is still a mystery, but it's what you're ordering by. Order by starttime, endtime if you want to enforce ordering on those.

Comment: If you look carefully on starttime and endtime from Thursday 
values is mixing. 12:00:00, 16:00:00, 08:00:00 I want 08:00:00, 12:00:00, 16:00:00 

before Thursday is fine